# Access WooCommerce custom post field in same action as send email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

*Before this gets flagged as a duplicate of [Save custom post fields value before Woocommerce email send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26251858/save-custom-post-fields-value-before-woocommerce-email-send) I will point out that the answer given to that question is a) not accepted and b) refers to a hook that is no longer in the documentation.*

---

I'm helping out a friend with their WordPress WooCommerce site, and they want to be able to add a tracking number to the email that gets automatically sent out to a customer once the order status is set to "Completed". I've managed to get this all working using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin and some code in functions.php. The problem I have is the user friendliness isn't quite there when it comes to processing the order, it being a double-barrelled operation:

1. Fill in the tracking number custom field on the Edit Order screen and then click the Update button
2. Set the status to Completed and the click the Update button again

Ideally, it would be nice to fill in the tracking number text field *and* change the status dropdown value to Completed, and then hit update. If that is done though, the email doesn't get the custom field populated, presumably because the custom fields get saved *after* the email gets triggered.

Is there a hook in WooCommerce that allows, on update of the order, saving of custom fields to occur before triggering the email?

For reference, this is my current code in functions.php, where (despite changing the priority of the operation to 1) it doesn't populate the tracking number on the email:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'add_content_specific_email', 1, 4 );
function add_content_specific_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
   if ( $email->id == 'customer_completed_order' ) {
      $ausPostTrackingNumber = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(),'australia_post_tracking_number',true);
      if($ausPostTrackingNumber != '') {
         echo '<p class="email-auspost-text">Your Australia Post tracking number is <a href="https://auspost.com.au/track/track.html?id=' . $ausPostTrackingNumber . '">' . $ausPostTrackingNumber . '</a></p>';          
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Plugins that add a tracking number use ajax and a "save tracking number" button.  This is how I would do it also.

Comment: @HowardE I couldn't find any free plugins that do this though. Also, AJAX seems a bit of overkill here - the post operation is doing the two things I need it to, just in the wrong order. I would have thought the `$priority` parameter in `add_action()` would take care of this, but alas no

Comment: Yeah... I'm referring to the one developed by WooCommerce.  I have a few clients who use it.  I mean... if that's what they do... seems logical.

Comment: Cool. I just installed this one, does everything I need it to. I wish I'd found it this morning, cheers @HowardE  https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-advanced-shipment-tracking/